# Can Apple's Notes handle pictures pasted from Clipboard?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, notes.app

I was viewing an article and taking random screenshots from interesting parts and pasting them in Notes. Today I open Notes and the pictures are gone, and Notes crashes if I try to select the missing pictures. (Their area is still there taking up space.)

Any idea if this is normal? How can I recover the images?

Comment: Did you happen to paste content from the web into your notes alongside the images? I think there's a bug in how notes handles html. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/402525/does-mac-os-notes-struggle-with-pasted-html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question is yes, sort of. Notes in Mac OS can handle pictures either dragged in or pasted in from the clipboard. I didn't know this would work but just tried it and it worked perfectly.

My Notes syncs with both my iPad and iPhone through iCloud. In iOS the image pasted into a note on my Mac is represented by a paper clip and deleting that paper clip on an iOS device does not seem to delete the picture on Mac OS even after sync, so it doesn't work quite as well as I'd like with iCloud and iOS but works fine with Mac OS.

My guess is this capability is going to be expanded in a future version of notes and this is a place marker.

Comment: In fact, Notes for OS X works with any file attachment dragged or pasted into notes, not just photos.

Comment: True, but I lost some photos from Notes and I cannot recover them as they were pasted from clipboard.

Comment: @Fendi: I don't use it and can't speak to it's stability but my guess is the capability is there as a place marker for notes turning into something like a super scrapbook. If you're losing things either it's not stable (yet) or you might try throwing out the notes prefs file to see if it's corrupted in some way.

Comment: Would like more explanation please. You think the pictures are still stored in the contents somewhere ?